# Derived and specialised template classes that contain each other

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code inside a header (edited):

```
template <int i> class A {};
template <> class A <1> { B<1> _b; };

template <int i> class B : public A <i> {};
template <> class B <1> : public A <1> {};
```

And somehow use it like this:

```
#include "template_A_B.h"
int main ()
{
   A<1> a;
   B<1> b;
   return 0;
}
```

Obviously I get the compilation error:

```
error: ‘B’ does not name a type
```

If I add a forward declaration of B like

```
template <int i> class B;
```

I get

```
error: field ‘_b’ has incomplete type
```

when compiling.

I also tried forward declaring A and switching the order of the class definitions and get:

```
error: declaration of ‘struct A<1>’
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Any practical use of such class design?

Comment: @Nawaz: A is an array class that can contain an a derived class B as an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original formulation of your question, you simply needed to put your specializations after your forward declarations. Then everything will be resolved correctly.

```
template <int i> class A;
template <int i> class B;

template <> class A <1> {};
template <> class B <1> : public A <1> {};

template <int i> class A { B<1> _b; };
template <int i> class B : public A <i> {};
```

In your revised question, you have created a structure that is trying to contain itself, which isn't allowed even with non-template types. For example, you are not allowed to define:

```
struct A { B b; };
struct B : public A {};
```

However, you can perform something close to what you want if you change `A` to use an indirect reference to `B`.

```
struct B;

struct A { B *b; };
struct B : public A {};
```

Comment: thanks for this clarification. I understand this better now. Anyway (sorry for that): I had to edit the question. The member of type B<1> is now in the specialised version of A. Again, compilation errors...

Comment: @steffen: You have defined a pair of structures with recursive containment. That's not allowed.

Comment: Does that mean that "being derived of" is in that sense similar to "containig"?

Comment: @steffen: `B` is a `A` and `A` has a `B`. So you are trying to create a `B` that has a `B`. Follow that recursive chain, and your structure has an infinitely long definition.